# SQLite error (5): database is locked C# Dapper

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

Использую в проекте SQLite (устанавливал через NuGet) и Dapper.
В проекте используется пул потоков для чтения из БД, запись в БД производится из отдельного потока по очереди.
Насколько понимаю SQLite собран уже для многопоточности. 
The default mode is serialized.

Периодически в выводе проскакивает SQLite error (5): database is locked, даже не понятно, что именно выбросило это исключение, но при этом программа работает как нужно. Стоит ли обращать на это внимание или нужно исправлять? Как?

Comment: Добавил в строку подключения такие опции: Synchronous=off;FailIfMissing=True;Journal Mode=Off; Пока не вижу такой ошибки..хм..

Comment: При использовании Dapper + SQLite ловил подобное. В моем случае решилось оборачиванием _connection, который использовал для подключения, в using.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda можно подробнее?